# Delete Azure blob using REST api with CURL PHP

Tags: php, azure, curl, azure-blob-storage

How can I delete a blob using REST API and cURL in PHP?

```
$headers = [
        'Authorization: ',
        'x-ms-blob-cache-control: max-age=3600',
        'x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob',
        'x-ms-date: ' . $currentDate,
        'x-ms-version: 2020-10-10'
    ];
```

How can I create Authorization header here and do I need more headers?

Comment: Do you have any update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared access signature to call Azure Blob REST API. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas).

for example

```
<?php
        $signedResource="b";
        $signedSnapshotTime ="";
        $signedVersion="2020-04-08";
        $resourceName="<containerName>/<blobName>";
        $signedPermissions="rd";
        $signedExpiry= gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('+1 day'));
        $signedStart = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('-1 day'));;
        $signedIP = "";
        $signedProtocol = "";
        $signedIdentifier = "";
        $cacheControl = "";
        $contentDisposition = "";
        $contentEncoding = "";
        $contentLanguage = "";
        $contentType = "";
        $accountName="andyprivate";
        $accountKey="";
        $canonicalizedResource=sprintf('/%s/%s/%s', "blob", $accountName, $resourceName);
        $parameters = array();
        $parameters[] = $signedPermissions;
        $parameters[] = $signedStart;
        $parameters[] = $signedExpiry;
        $parameters[] = $canonicalizedResource;
        $parameters[] = $signedIdentifier;
        $parameters[] = $signedIP;
        $parameters[] = $signedProtocol;
        $parameters[] = $signedVersion;
        $parameters[] = $signedResource;
        $parameters[] = $signedSnapshotTime;
        $parameters[] = $cacheControl;
        $parameters[] = $contentDisposition;
        $parameters[] = $contentEncoding;
        $parameters[] = $contentLanguage;
        $parameters[] = $contentType;
        $stringToSign = implode("\n", $parameters);
        echo $stringToSign;
        echo "\n";
        $decodedAccountKey = base64_decode($accountKey);
        $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $stringToSign, $decodedAccountKey, true);
        // decode the account key from base64
        $decodedAccountKey = base64_decode($accountKey);
        // create the signature with hmac sha256
        $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $stringToSign, $decodedAccountKey, true);
        // encode the signature as base64
        $sig = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

        $buildOptQueryStr = function ($string, $abrv) {
            return $string === '' ? '' : $abrv . $string;
        };
        //adding all the components for account SAS together.
        $sas = 'sv=' . $signedVersion;
        $sas .= '&sr=' . $signedResource;
        $sas .= $buildOptQueryStr($cacheControl, '&rscc=');
        $sas .= $buildOptQueryStr($contentDisposition, '&rscd=');
        $sas .= $buildOptQueryStr($contentEncoding, '&rsce=');
        $sas .= $buildOptQueryStr($contentLanguage, '&rscl=');
        $sas .= $buildOptQueryStr($contentType, '&rsct=');

        $sas .= $buildOptQueryStr($signedStart, '&st=');
        $sas .= '&se=' . $signedExpiry;
        $sas .= '&sp=' . $signedPermissions;
        $sas .= $buildOptQueryStr($signedIP, '&sip=');
        $sas .= $buildOptQueryStr($signedProtocol, '&spr=');
        $sas .= $buildOptQueryStr($signedIdentifier, '&si=');
        $sas .= '&sig=' . $sig;
        $url =  'https://'.$accountName.'.blob.core.windows.net'.'/'
            .$resourceName .'?'.$sas;
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'DELETE',
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        echo $response;

?>
```